# How to make a jsonp call to an api using jquery

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp

I am new to programming in general and i am having trouble getting the data into my web app when i make a call to the moviedb.org api. I am using jquery and i have read all the docs, even the cookbook and i am still struggling to make this work, i also checked my google dev tools console and it shows that the call was successful:

```
Status Code:200 OK
[{"id":550,"name":"Fight Club","posters":[{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"original","height":1000,"width":675,"url":"http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/f8e/4b........
```

Here is my code:

```
<script>
   $.getJSON("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
         $("<img/>").attr("src", item.image).appendTo("#images");
      });
    });
 </script>
```

I think i am messing up with the callback function, any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `api.themoviedb.org/2.1` version of the API doesn't support `JSONP`. [Their docs says it is supported in the version 3 API](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/about-3): `Unlike previous versions of the API, /3 only supports a single format, JSON. XML and YAML support are being officially dropped. This lets us focus on improving 1 single type and also increases our ability to reuse cached data. JSONP is also officially supported, just add a callback parameter and you’re done.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the server you're hitting doesn't seem to support JSONP, this is server-side functionality that must be present...and isn't.  I also see no mention in their API docs or forums.  The URL should be `?callback=?` since it's the only querystring parameter, like this:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/<apikey>/550&callback=?
```

...but that still won't work, since the server doesn't support it.  Just as an aside: Many times something with an API key *isn't* going to support JSONP (since the client would have the key), if the API it using the key to restrict access...others using it just for tracking may not care.

Comment: This is incorrect. The `callback=?` is actually altered by jQuery to replace the `?` with a generated function name. Try replacing `?` with say `foobar` and you'll see valid data returned: `http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=foobar`

Comment: @hippietrail - No...the answer is still correct, what's returned with your URL is **not** JSONP, it's not wrapped in a `foobar(<datahere>);` function call, it's just JSON data.  Test it before saying it's wrong :)  I'm aware of how jQuery works with the JSONP parameters...but that's not relevant at all if the server you're calling doesn't support JSONP, which is why that's focused on in this answer.

Comment: Oops that API key seems to no longer be valid so I can't check )-:

Comment: @hippietrail - You can try it with any API key, fact remains...that service doesn't support JSONP.  Since you can't get past that, the specifics of how jQuery works need not be expounded upon in this answer, since no matter which client-side library you're using, it won't work.  Also, the answer is saying which URL he should use *in his code* (the **only** place it appears in the question), so even in that respect, what's incorrect with this answer?

Comment: @NickCraver: Yes you're right, I was able to find the old results I downloaded when the API key was still valid. But perhaps the OP gave the wrong parameter for the callback? Let me check the API docs...

Comment: OK so according to [the API documentation](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/about-3), `themoviedb.org` only supports `JSONP` from API version 3 and the OP's question uses API version 2.1 but as before I can't verify this without a valid API key.

Comment: @hippietrail - The API key in the original post still works, try your own URL to see it doesn't work: [http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=foobar](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=foobar).  All of the documentation confirms this, I'm not sure why you assume I'm an idiot here, the answer covers all of this already...and the API 3.0 documentation confirms my answer.

Comment: I'm not assuming you're an idiot at all, but I am in a crowded room with lots of drinking and a crappy internet connection so probably too many distractions for me to participate in this after all. In any case I've tried to reverse my downvote but Stack Exchange won't let me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to make sure the api your calling supports jsonp (if it doesn't you will see the json but you won't be able to do anything with it).

Second. If you don't add a callback name so you leave the ?callback=? then jquery will add a random number to the end of your url and will most likely cause a problem. It would look like this:

```
http://someurl.com?callback=140989239
```

That only hurts you.  In standard jsonp you actually insert the json into a `<script>` tag. To do that your going to want to do something like the following:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = "text/javascript";
newScript.src = "enter your api url that you are calling here with a specified callback"
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: "First of all you have to make sure the api your calling supports jsonp (if it doesn't you will see the json but you won't be able to do anything with it)."      Yes, i see it in the console but can't access it. I also see the radom numbers genrated for the callback function name. Thanks Matt!

Comment: So now to access the json that it returns specify a callback. So do something like this:   function makeRequest ( $.getJSON("url?callback=someCallback", {...}); ) and then have another function called the name of your callback name so in this case "someCallback".  function someCallback { do what you want with the json in here}    If this doesn't work then the api doesn't support jsonp yet.  Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This function "post" call the server

```
$.post("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=?", 
   function(data){ 
    //After the server code run, this code is executed with the 
    //information of the response into the parameter 'data'
    $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
    $("").attr("src", item.image).appendTo("#images");
    });
   }, 
 json");
```

As you can see, I put the same "each" iteration function. I do not know if you're doing it correctly, because I don't execute this code. But I strongly recommend that you try execute the code into the function(data)... with an alert(...) as I show below:

```
$.post("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getImages/en/json/ed7e2e092ca896037ce13d2bf11a08f1/550&callback=?", 
   function(data){
    alert(data);
   }, 
"json");
```

With this do you really know what s "data" vale.

I hope you have been helpful.